# How to remove a specific section from bookmarks

Tags: bookmarks, sections-paragraphs

I'm trying to find a way to remove a specific section from the bookmarks.
Suppose I have the following code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}   
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}    
\section{Introduction}
\section{Conclusion}
\end{document}
```

Could someone please help me with this?

Thank you very much !!!

Comment: Hello! When you ask questions here, it's _really_ helpful (and would probably get you an answer faster) if you provide a _complete_ and _self contained_ example. It means that if we can copy paste the code, we have something to work from. i.e. it should include a `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. This way we can just copy/paste the code and go straight into solving the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you really are asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can locally change the bookmarksdepth:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=-1}
\section{Conclusion}
\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth} %back
\section{Bookmark}
\end{document}
```

[image]